# Saving a graph with gnuplot on xubuntu

Tags: python, gnuplot

I have a python code that has the following line:

```
os.system("gnuplot data3.gnu")
```

my data3.gnu has the following commands

```
plot "data3.txt"
pause -1
set terminal png 
set output 'plot10.png'
```

so what i want it to do is show me the plot which it does then when i exit it saves the plot to a file called "plot10.png"  it is ploting data3.txt fine however it is not saving the file.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you need to `set` terminal and output before actually plotting anything. However, it then won't show the plot since the data is written straight to the disk.

In Gnuplot 5, there should an export button in the GUI, but in case you don't have it or are looking for a way to save programmatically, use [`replot`](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node150.html) to repeat the last plotting command:

```
plot "data3.txt"
pause -1
set terminal png 
set output 'plot10.png'
replot
```